How to add a timestamp watermark onto a video and a photo?
How to add capture data and time timestamp watermark from metadata to videos and photos with Date and time format - EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy, hh:mm a' with same files name without any changes, without any error in Windows PC.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Can you share with us things you have tried and research you have done?

You can use drawtext with the %{metadata} funcion. For example to get the Date of the input file:
drawtext=text='%{metadata\:DateTime}
As an example:
ffmpeg -i "input" -vf "drawtext=fontsize=150:fontcolor=white:bordercolor=black:borderw=10:font='calibri':x=50:y=50:text='Date\: %{metadata\:datetime}',drawtext=fontsize=150:fontcolor=white:bordercolor=black:borderw=10:font='calibri':x=50:y=200:text='Camera Model\: %{metadata\:model}',drawtext=fontsize=150:fontcolor=white:bordercolor=black:borderw=10:font='calibri':x=50:y=350:text='Brand\: %{metadata\:make}',drawtext=fontsize=150:fontcolor=white:bordercolor=black:borderw=10:font='calibri':x=50:y=500:text='Dimensions\: %{metadata\:PixelXDimension} X %{metadata\:PixelYDimension}',scale=800:-1'" -y output.jpg

To get a list of the metadata that you can use you can use ffprobe:
ffprobe -show_frames "input.jpg"

